# How to read the birthdate of a contact in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I am making an android app, and for that app, I need to read the birth dates of the contacts stored in my address book. Is there any code for that. [How to read contacts on Android 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721279/how-to-read-contacts-on-android-2-0) shows the code to read the phone numbers and email addresses, but the code to read birth dates is not available. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8579883/562935

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE` and set the `TYPE` to `TYPE_BIRTHDAY`

- [ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.html#START_DATE)

  ```
      Uri uri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
      String[] projection = new String[] {
              ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
              ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTACT_ID,
              ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE
      };

      String where =
              ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "= ? AND " +
              ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE + 
              "=" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY;
      String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { 
          ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };
  ```