# How to insert contact birthday date by intent

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I use this code to simply add a contact:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION);
    intent.setType(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE);

    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, edNome.getText().toString() + ' ' + edCognome.getText().toString())
            .putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, edCellulare.getText().toString())
            .putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE_TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE);

    startActivity(intent);
```

I need to insert also birthday date. I saw there is the option "ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event" but how do I add this to the intent?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider please try to explore this link

Comment: I have already looked out about this page. But I don't find any useful help. I wrote my code using this url

Comment: you want to get birthday please explore this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579883/get-birthday-for-each-contact-in-android-application

Comment: I want to SET birthday date

Answer (score 1):

You can add birthday like below code:

Here 1 is value of `calendarId` for birthday.

```
   private void addEvent(){

        ContentResolver cr = ((Activity)Forms.Context).ContentResolver;
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        String eventUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/events";

//Insert Events in the calendar...
        values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.CalendarId, 1);
        values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Title, title);
        values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Status, 1);
        values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Description, description);
        values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtstart, GetDateTimeMS(year, month, day, hour, minute));
        values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtend, GetDateTimeMS(year, month, day, hour, minute));
        values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.AllDay, allday ? "1" : "0");
        values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.HasAlarm, hasalarm ? "1" : "0");
        values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventColor, Android.Graphics.Color.Green);
        values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventTimezone, "GMT+" + zone + ":00");
        values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventEndTimezone, "GMT+" + zone + ":00");
        cr.Insert(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(eventUriString), values);
    }
```

Comment: Why calendar? I need contact. There isn't any intent here

Comment: @ChetanJosh, It's a good example to create a birthday event. But it is not recurring every year. And how do you get the year, month, day?

Comment: @XueQing its long time back I have used , but you can se start and end date that will help you for recursion.

Answer (score 0):

you can't modify a contact's birthday via intent, you must use `ContactsContract` APIs to modify contacts.

According to the docs at: https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/modify-data#EditContact
You can only edit via intent the list of attributes at:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Intents.Insert
Which contains data items like emails and phones, but birthdays or events are not on the list.

The closest thing is to just open the contact's edit screen and have the user add the birthday herself:

```
Intent editIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
editIntent.setDataAndType(theContactUri, Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
startIntent(editIntent);
```