# Access the birth date of a specific contact and Remove Duplicate contact results in android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-cursor

I have tried two solution from the links given below, but I am not getting the correct results. The dates are getting mixed up and duplicated to other contacts. Links to the tried solutions are - [Android 2.2 Contact Birthday Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376980/android-2-2-contact-birthday-date)

and  [Get birthday for each contact in Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579883/get-birthday-for-each-contact-in-android-application)

Comment: you can check the code given in these two links - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376980/android-2-2-contact-birthday-date and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579883/get-birthday-for-each-contact-in-android-application
I have implemented that code only.